# gwt jsni variable name obfuscated

Tags: javascript, gwt, eval, jsni

I am having trouble trying to use javascript eval() with gwt.

Basically, I have in my DB a dynamic string, for example:

```
"'31.07.'  + (myVar.getMonth() <= 7 ? myVar.getFullYear() + 3: myVar.getFullYear() + 4 )"
```

myVar is supposed to be a javascript variable of type date.

This variable is passed via GWT JSNI:

```
private native String eval(Date dateFieldValue, String scriptlet) /*-{
  var myVar = dateFieldValue;
  return $wnd.eval(scriptlet);
}-*/;
```

But the "myVar" variable in the scriptlet string is not being found. 
I found this: 
https://support.google.com/code/answer/55205?hl=en

Which explains why this happens. 
I would have to separate my scriptlet in such a way:

```
"'31.07.'  + (" + myVar + ".getMonth() <= 7 ? " + myVar + ".getFullYear() + 3: " + myVar + ".getFullYear() + 4 )"
```

The problem is that this would not be flexible, since the scriptlet is administered in the database, not in the code. So what to do in this case? Is this impossible?

Comment: Code obfuscation is an option, you could simply turn if off.

Comment: But gwt will still change variable names, or? having to turn obfuscation would be too much only for this I think.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but could can be an option in a moment of desperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function instead:

```
return (new Function('myVar', 'return ' + scriptlet))(dateFieldValue);
```

That's still as bad as `eval` security-wise but much cleaner anyway.

Comment: This would have the same problem, as the scriptlet is a string and gwt does not read inside the string.

Comment: No it wouldn't (until proven otherwise), because 'myVar' now is a string passed as argument to `new Function` to name its argument, so it won't be rewritten by GWT. This is basically equivalent, if you'd prefer that, to `eval('function(myVar) { return ' + scriptlet + '}')(dateFieldValue)`

Comment: This sounds promising, thanks! I have tried different variants but it is still not working: Simple Scriptlet: `String scriptlet = "myVar.getMonth()";` and the function: `private native String eval(Date myDate, String scriptlet) /*-{
   return (new Function('myVar', 'return ' + scriptlet))(myDate);
 }-*/; ` but I get: "myVar.getMonth is not a function". What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Even more simplified but still the same. Something is wrong I am not sure what. `private native String eval(Date myDate) /*-{
   return (new Function('myVar', 'return myVar.getFullYear()'))(myDate);
 }-*/; `

Comment: This works: `private native String eval(Date myDate) /*-{
   return (new Function('myVar', 'return myVar.getFullYear()'))(new Date());
 }-*/; ` but the same with `myDate`instead of `new Date()`doesn't. What is happening here ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. For anyone interested: it worked using a helper function: `private static native JavaScriptObject timeToJsObject(double time) /*-{
     return new Date(time);
   }-*/;` then calling the function: `private native String eval(JavaScriptObject theDate, String scriptlet) /*-{
   return (new Function('theDate', 'return ' + scriptlet))(theDate);
 }-*/; ` with a scriptlet e.g. `String scriptlet = "theDate.getFullYear()";`